# Rectangular matrix for Tikhonov first order regularization

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

I need to construct a rectangular matrix L, (n-1)xn, that has a form:

[image]

Does anyone a practical way to do it in Mathematica?

Comment: Also explore `FitRegularization`.

Comment: My first attempt would have been ToeplitzMatrix[{-1,0,...}, {-1, 1,0,...}] and get rid of the last row. Not sure why OP considers this complex enough to ask. Is there any hidden complexity?

Answer (score 8):

```
ClearAll[sa]

sa[n_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {n - 1, n}]


sa[5]
```

[image]

```
Normal @ sa[5]
```

> ```
> {{-1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1,  1}}
> ```

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ sa[5]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[tm]

tm[n_] := ReplaceAll[1 -> Sequence[-1, 1]] @ IdentityMatrix[n - 1]

tm[5] == Normal @ sa[5]
```

> ```
> True
> ```